# Table View Cell has no Initialiser

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, storyboard

I am trying to display table view cell property into different table view cell when button I clicked . I am using story board . I added the Horizontal and vertical stack to contains the image and label properties . I want to display this property into another table view cell when user clicked the show button . In cellFor row function i defined the button action property . I am getting following error .**Class 'DetailsViewCell' has no initializers**. **Cannot use instance member 'mc' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available**

Here is the screenshot of the both view controller .
[image]

Here is the code .

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MovieCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? MovieCell
//        else { return UITableViewCell() }
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MovieViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MovieViewCell
        
        
        cell.showButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.showButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("movieDetails"), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let row = indexPath.row
        let title = presenter.getTitle(by: row)
        let overview = presenter.getOverview(by: row)
        let data = presenter.getImageData(by: row)
        cell.configureCell(title: title, overview: overview, data: data)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is the code in identifier class with table view cell.

```
class MovieViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "MovieViewCell"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mainStackView: UIStackView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var movieImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var movieTtile: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var movieOverview: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var showButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func movieDetails(_ sender: UIButton) {

        
        var  dc : DetailsViewCell
        movieTtile = dc.movieTitle
        movieOverview = dc.movieOverview
        movieImage = dc.movieImage
        
        
    }
    
    
    func configureCell(title: String?, overview: String?, data: Data?) {
        
        movieTtile.text = title
        movieOverview.text = overview
        
        if let imageData = data{
            movieImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Details view cell.

```
class DetailsViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var movieTitle: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var movieOverview: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var movieImage: UIImageView!
    

         var mc : MovieViewCell
        
         movieTitle = mc.movieTtile
         movieOverview = mc.movieOverview
         movieImage = mc.movieImage
        
    
    
}
```

Comment: The cells don't know each other. Your approach is wrong anyway. The controller is supposed to maintain the UI. Manipulating the cells directly causes unexpected behavior at the moment the user scrolls.

Comment: what is the correct approach ?@vadian

Comment: As I said the controller is the manager to update the cells. You need to change the model and then call `reloadData()`

Comment: sorry it not clear to me @vadian

Comment: I trying different approach like delegate

Comment: Are the cells in different view controllers? If yes then you have to pass data via the segue. Please read or watch tutorials to learn how table views work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit

var loginData = ["", "", ""]

class LoginDataCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtLoginData: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 0 {
       loginData[0] = textField.text
    } else if textField.tag == 1 {
      loginData[1] = textField.text
    } else if textField.tag == 2 {
      loginData[2] = textField.text
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.